# Botpress concatenate variable, as argument, in execute code action form

Tags: javascript, chatbot

I know if I pass `{{variable}}` (like a `{{event.text}}`) in args field of action form works fine.

[image]

But, when I try concatenate this variable with a another String, this not work.

[image]

Result in **{{state.api_url}}/users** string, and I need **http//myapi.com/users**

Is it possible?

Comment: did you find any solution? i an also stuck here

Answer (score 1):

I may have an *extremely kludgy* workaround for this based on bad javascript.

I was looking to iterate a temp variable downwards. I did the assignment **in the raw code box for a transition**

Good code like `temp.variable==1` would be a true/false test.

But **just using one equals sign performs the assignment**.

So `temp.variable=temp.variable-1` in the raw code box subtracted one from my (numeric value) variable.

This seems to return False for the purposes of the transition so it doesn't matter where you point it as long as it's in the chain.

It seems to work for me, anyway.

I'm properly not sure what your code would look like, perhaps you make a new variable then do a transition with

```
temp.variable_you_just_made=state.api_url+'/users'
```

then call that variable doing your url thing?

[Looking around I come to suspect the correct thing would be to make a new action https://botpress.io/docs/10.0/getting_started/trivia_actions/ but I am new to all this]